# Стилизация input color

Tags: css

Появилась потребность в стилизации `input[type="color"]`. Уже сколько пытаюсь, никак не могу понять всех стилей этого объекта. Помогите стилизовать и сделать так, как на картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моя попытка:

```css
input[type="color"] {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.color {position: relative;}
.color:after {
  display: block; 
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="color"><input type="color"></div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11471224
Стилизация нативных элементов браузера всегда больно.
Так что, имхо, сгодятся любые варианты.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Стилизовать такое с помощью одного `input color` вряд ли выйдет. Я бы советовал воспользоваться дополнительными элементами:

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input[type="color"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  background: #fff;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
  cursor: inherit;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 30px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: inherit;
}

/* -webkit */
input[type="color"]::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
  padding: 0;    
}

input[type="color"]::-webkit-color-swatch {
  border: none;  
  border-radius: 50%;
}


/* firefox */
input[type=color]::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input[type=color]::-moz-color-swatch {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 140px;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="color">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 3):

[Can i use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-color)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.color-picker {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.color-picker::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.color-picker__control {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}


/* -webkit */

.color-picker__control::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
  padding: 0;
}

.color-picker__control::-webkit-color-swatch {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
}


/* firefox */

.color-picker__control::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.color-picker__control::-moz-color-swatch {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="color-picker">
  <input class="color-picker__control" type="color" value="#000">
</div>
```

Comment: Ого. Спасибо огромное! Через 4 минуты приму :)

Comment: Стоп. А почему серединка красится? Должны ведь бока..